# fetch on react component method with problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

Im trying to make an API CALL using fetch in a method (saveUser). API is working fine and de method is doing his work well but I dont know why the PUT doesnt work.

Here is the code:

```
saveUser(user: IUser) {
  user = this.state.user;
  let userId = user._id;
  let url = `http://localhost:4200/api/update-user/${userId}`;

  fetch(url, {
             method: 'put',
             body: JSON.stringify(user),
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             }
       }).then(res => res.json())
       .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
       .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
       debugger;
    };
```

Here is all the code: [manageUserPage](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2e63p8bfounij2/manageUserPage.tsx?dl=0)

Comment: what error you're getting on console "

Comment: of course you tested API with postman and put method ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response! Yes, it works on postman correctly and with de JSON.

Comment: I doesn't shows anything on console. When I use postman it shows the user modified correctly. Thats why i think that the problem is on the method.

Comment: What error code you're getting in response ?

Comment: I do not have response on terminal. Only i have response when I make the call via postman. So the problem on the method.

Comment: see you network tab in devtools

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in your `request` like this:

```
fetch(url, {
             method: 'PUT',
             body: JSON.stringify(user),
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             }
```

Let me know if the issue still persists and make sure you have enabled CORS.

Comment: Make it uppercase

Comment: I updated the post with the rest of the code. Thanks again for all your help. :)